# Moving a Shape in a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to move a shape when a user selects Yes or No from a dropdown list. I thought this would be simple, namely cut & paste the shape using VBA, but it does not seem to work that way.

Below image as a visual representation:

[image]

The objective is to bring the shape into view (cell CC18) when selected yes, and out of view (ideally on another sheet, but can also move to the same sheet) when select no.

I ran the `Macro Recorder` and got the below code:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("shpAPEX")).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("CH18").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Obviously this is not ideal, so I tried to translate that into something cleaner, namely:

```vb
ws.Shapes("shpAPEX").Cut
ws.Range("CC18").Paste
```

But this does not work. It cuts the shape, but does not paste it. I can see this by finding the shape in the clipboard.

However, the below code works:

```vb
ws.Shapes("shpAPEX").Cut
ws.Range("CC18").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Can anyone please explain to me why my initial attempt does not work, and also what is the best way to move shapes between worksheets?

Comment: Why not just change its visible property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to change the shape's `visible` property:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A1" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Visible = (Target.Value = "Yes")
End If

End Sub
```

However, if that is not desirable or a problem, you could keep the shape on another sheet and then just copy it to sheet1 or delete. This might need some adjustment if you have other shapes on the sheet, and error trapping in case there is no shape when trying to delete:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim s As Shape

Set s = Sheet2.Shapes("Rectangle 1") 'shape on another sheet

If Target.Address(0, 0) = "A1" Then
    If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        s.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste 'then use top/left etc to position
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Delete
    End If
End If

End Sub
```